# Is this possible to read internal CPU temp sensor directly from cpp code?

Tags: sensor, c++, ds18b20, 1-wire

I am working on the kind of RPi platform to collect some external sensors data or control relays (using the remote tools like web or sms).

Next problem I am tring to solve now is to get the direct access to one-wire or internal temp sensor.

Most examples I have found seems to access data by reading the system/drivers files.

What I am interested in is the direct access just from the cpp code.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "internal CPU temp" you mean the sensor built into the pi's SoC, I guess you could get direct access by `mmap()`ing the right part of the kernel, but since it already exposes an inteface to userspace, that seems a bit silly.

Where it's exposed depends on how your kernel is configured (see "Thermal Sensor" at [the bottom here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/kernel-config-necessary-options)), but it is somewhere in `/sys` and the value is in thousandths of a degree Celcius.

Files in `/sys` are not real files.  They are just nodes in userspace. This is a language agnostic kernel interface. When you read one, you are requesting information from the kernel; when you write to one, you are sending it information.  So there is no instrinsic I/O overhead.

Occasionally I run across people who do not like this; they want a fancier API with system calls or `ioctl()` options or something generally more complicated looking (because of course, more complicated == better and faster...or maybe not).  But `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`, (or higher level equivalents) necessary to using the language agnostic interface *are* system calls.

That's how it works.  If that is distasteful to you, you'll have to write your own driver, or use the pi-specific stuff joan pointed to<sup>1</sup> -- but that seems a complete waste of time.  You just want a single scalar, the CPU temperature.  This wheel has been invented already.

> direct access just from the cpp code

Note that (excepting use of `mmap()`) you cannot do that with hardware, period.  That is part of the purpose of an operating system kernel.  If you are not familiar with the distinction between *kernel space* and *user space*, now is the time to [start learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space).

---

<sup>1.  Since `vcgencmd` can also provide this information, you might look at the stuff in `/opt/vc` (on Raspbian) to see if there is any relevant source there -- but again, why bother?</sup>

Comment: You did it. I agree - "that seems a bit silly" :) Thanks

Comment: Note I'm not sure if that driver is loaded automatically (just noticed it isn't on one of mine here, but I don't use the stock kernel).  Try `modprobe bcm2835-hwmon` and if that's "not found", `modprobe bcm2835-thermal`.  You should then be able to find the relevant nodes somewhere in `/sys`, lol, although the names might not be exactly as they are in that other post.  You can check them easily, e.g., `cat temp1_input`, = 40622.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mailbox interface](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki/Mailbox-property-interface) from C/C++ to get the SOC's temperature.

I'm not sure what you mean re the 1-wire bus.  You could bit bang the protocol to read a DS18B20 directly if you want.  There is [C code](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=569464#p569464) to do so available for the Raspberry Pi (some uses the [UART](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/214) for the timing, some doesn't).

However I can see no advantage over using the standard driver.

Comment: Thank you, will read more on it but from my point of view and based on @goldilock post, it seems, I will stay with drivers finally..