# Install older kernel (3.6.11+) on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: video, kernel, cross-compilation

Somewhere in the upgrade from the 3.6.11+ kernel to the 3.10 kernel, the ability to receive video through a USB capture card broke (capture card is based on the stk1160 chipset).  It is documented in [this github issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/620).  I've tried upgrading to the latest kernel (4.1.4-v7), and the issue still persists.  In testing on a Raspberry Pi B+, the functionality works again only when I've installed a 3.6.11+ (or older) kernel, and breaks past that kernel version.

I'm hoping to try and install this kernel older 3.6.11+ on a Raspberry Pi 2.  So far I have attempted cross compiling the 3.6.11+ source using the arm-linux-gnueabi- toolchain and bcmrpi_defconfig configs, but I get the [rainbow screen](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20rainbow%20screen&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=971&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoA2oVChMIg9mRlt2jxwIVQVseCh1UKApZ) on boot, which I'm assuming means there was a problem with my kernel (I verified this by swapping out my kernel image for the official 3.18 while keeping everything else the same, and I was able to boot).  I believe my cross-compilation process is correct, as this image that I am able to cross compile and load onto and SD card will boot on a Raspberry Pi B+.

I feel like this has to do with the fact that the 3.6.11+ source wasn't designed to work with the ARMv7 architecture, and that I somehow need to account for this in my compilation process.  So, my question is, is it possible to install the 3.6.11+ kernel on the Pi 2, and secondly, what steps/configs am I missing in this process?

Edit:  An alternate course of action for me (I think) would be recompiling the old source for the kernel modules relevant to video capture against a more recent kernel (like 3.18).  Is this easier or more feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I led you down a bit of a garden path earlier; this should have occurred to me as soon as you used 3.6.11 and Pi 2 in the same sentence.  Sorry about that.

`bcmrpi_defconfig` will not work with the Pi 2.  For that a new defconfig was added, `bcm2709_defconfig`.  These are all in `[src]/arch/arm/configs`.  However, it's not there for 3.6.11.

Looking through [the git branches](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.18.y/arch/arm/configs), it does not appear until 3.18, which is presumably when they added code for the Pi 2.  Even if you tried to configure this yourself, the options simply are not there. I checked this for 3.6.11; see the section about "System" [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24093/5538) for some background.

You are definitely out of luck here.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this issue greatly, either way.  It's been a learning experience to say the least.  Would recompiling the older kernel source against the updated kernel headers possibly solve this?  Do you have any other ideas how I could get around this video capture problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can downgrade kernel version with `rpi-update` as well. All you need to have is the hash of that git hash of that particular firmware upgrade.

As per this [link](http://tech.enekochan.com/en/2014/03/08/upgradedowngrade-to-a-specific-firmware-kernel-version-with-rpi-update-in-raspbian/),

> You can upgrade/downgrade to any revision of Raspbians firmware using
>   rpi-update. For example if you want to install revision 3.10.25+ you
>   should execute this:
>
> `sudo rpi-update 2ef601a50b68eebeeb4dc3c6c525855961891be6` 
>   The long string represents the Git hash for the specific firmware >revision. You
>   can look for those hash in the rpi-update git repos commits list:
>   https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/master.

But I'm not sure if you can make it work with Rpi 2 as firmware update that comes with that old kernel would be pretty old and Rpi 2 was nt even there and therefore, it most likely will not support Rpi 2. But you are good to try.

Hope it helps.